# what could be wrong in this batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to let the user enter numbers and if they miss one I want the program to drop an error message. However If not Defined doesn't work.

```
set /p aa=a11: 
set /p ba=a12: 
set /p ba=a12: 
set /p ab=a21: 
set /P bb=a22: 
cls
echo antra matrica
echo.
set /p qq=b11: 
set /p wq=b12: 
set /p qw=b21: 
set /P ww=b22: 
for %%A IN (%aa%, %ba%, %ab%, %bb%, %qq%, %wq%, %qw%, %ww%) DO IF [%%A]==[] goto error
```

It ignores the for command. What could i do to make it work when all the variables are enterd blank?

Comment: `for %%A IN (aa, ba, ab, bb, qq, wq, qw, ww) DO IF NOT DEFINED %%A goto error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a different method:

```
set Count=0
for %%A IN (%aa%, %ba%, %ab%, %bb%, %qq%, %wq%, %qw%, %ww%) DO set /a Count+=1
if %Count% neq 8 goto error
```

This takes advantage of the fact that an undefined variable would not be processed with `for` (this was the problem with your original code)

Another advantage is, that now you could tell, how many of the variables were properly defined (if you want to know)

Comment: btw: you can delete the commas OR the spaces (consecutive delimiters are treated as one) But they don't disturb, you also can leave both for better readabiltiy.

Answer (score 0):

Aacini's solution will work, but two questions remain:

1. Why didn't "If not defined" work?
   and
2. Why didn't the command you've posted work?

As you've provided it, `cmd` will interpret the `for` command as

```
for %%A in (aas_value, bas_value, abs_value, ...) do if
```

So had you entered 4,*nothing*,5,6... then the command line would be

```
for %%A in (4, , 5, 6...) do if
```

**<kbd>,</kbd>** and <kbd>Space</kbd> are seen as separators, so this would be resolved as

> for %%A in (4*separatorsequence*5*separatorsequence*6...) do if

hence the missing value - er, goes missing.

If you'd used `...%var%...` and `if...defined` then since `4`,`5` and `6` are not defined environment variables, you'd get "if not defined" acting unexpectedly (ie "does not work *in the manner I expected but have kept to myself*")

Another approach would be

```
for %%A IN ("%aa%", "%ba%", "%ab%",...) DO IF [%%~A]==[] goto error
```

which would be interpreted as

> for %%A IN ("4"*separatorsequence*""*separatorsequence*"5",...) DO IF [%%~A]==[] goto error

Here, `"4"`, `""`, `"5"` would each be assigned to `%%A` - including the quotes. The tilde (**<kbd>~</kbd>**) removes the enclosing quotes, so `[%%~A]` would be evaluated to `[]` as expected.